# Fetching Images in Pentaho Reports Designer from BLOB field of Derby Database

Tags: image, report, blob, derby, pentaho

I am trying to display PNG images of person from BLOB field of Derby database in Pentaho Reports Designer using image-field. But, image is not displaying. I have also created below BSH function but didn't worked. What's wrong I am doing. please help.

```
Object getValue()
{
  var blobObject = dataRow.get("IMAGE");
  long blobLength = blobObject.length();
  byte[] blobContent = blobObject.getBytes((long)1, (int)blobLength);
  return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(blobContent);
}
```

I am getting below warning message in logs

```
2014-03-15 07:53:09,897 [45929284] WARN - org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.beanshell.BSHExpression - Evaluation error: class bsh.TargetError - Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``getValue ();'' : Method Invocation blobObject.getBinaryStream 
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``getValue ();'' : Method Invocation blobObject.getBinaryStream : at Line: 7 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``java.awt.Image getValue() { var blobObject = dataRow.get("IMAGE"); //long bl . . . '' : blobObject .getBinaryStream ( ) 

Called from method: getValue : at Line: 1 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``getValue ();'' : getValue ( ) 
Target exception: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot invoke other java.sql.Clob/java.sql.Blob methods after calling the free() method or after the Blob/Clob's transaction has been committed or rolled back. 

at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHArguments.getArguments(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHReturnStatement.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BshMethod.invokeImpl(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BshMethod.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BshMethod.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.Name.invokeLocalMethod(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source) 
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.beanshell.BSHExpression.getValue(BSHExpression.java:185) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.ExpressionEventHelper.evaluateSingleExpression(ExpressionEventHelper.java:822) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.ExpressionEventHelper.reactivateExpressions(ExpressionEventHelper.java:807) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.ExpressionDataRow.fireReportEvent(ExpressionDataRow.java:435) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.GlobalMasterRow.fireReportEvent(GlobalMasterRow.java:380) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.fireReportEvent(DefaultFlowController.java:447) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.fireReportEvent(ProcessState.java:1284) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.BeginDetailsHandler.advance(BeginDetailsHandler.java:51) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.advance(ProcessState.java:1076) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processPaginationLevel(AbstractReportProcessor.java:730) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:534) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.graphics.PrintReportProcessor.getNumberOfPages(PrintReportProcessor.java:78) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.gui.base.PreviewPane$RepaginationRunnable.run(PreviewPane.java:271) 
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.util.Worker.run(Worker.java:174)
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Comment: I have used MySql database instead of derby and it worked smoothly without using BSH expression. I have opened ticket with Pentaho. http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5004